# Maintain small file size while repeating video but not audio

Tags: video, compression

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
I have a short video clip that I want to repeat 10 times, but during that time I want it to play a single audio track.
This is easy enough to do in any video editor. However, the resulting video size is way bigger than it needs to be.
If the video clip is 5MB and the audio track is 2MB then the resulting video file should not be more than be 7MB.  However, the more times the video is repeated the larger the file becomes.
Does anyone know how to compress this video so it does not have that problem?

Comment: Have you googled "how to compress video"? Which method (or what piece of software) are you using?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. I do not know any video container file type which can control the flow of the stream data - only external video players can do that. Every stream in such container (including video stream) has linear data to read from, there are no possibilities to "loop the data" in a way you want. The only possibility to decrease the final file size of such file with looped stream is to decrease the quality of this stream by using some kind of data compression - and that is what you can do here.